# Octez-node cannot sync with mumbainet

Tags: node

I use a VM Ubuntu 22.04 (LTS) x64, 8 GB Memory & 160 GB  NVMe SSD Disk.

I followed this Guide: https://chrispinnock.com/tezos/node/ but instead mainnet I wanted to run mumbainet. The problem I have is it seems it cant sync? My goal is to try to originate a rollup, the gen keys command works when I follow this guide:  https://news.tezoscommons.org/setting-up-a-tezos-smart-rollup-in-5-steps-af62ed75a684 But the balance shows always 0 after I claimed from the faucet,  I suppose because its not synced?
These are my steps:

`apt update && apt upgrade`

`apt install libev4 libhidapi-libusb0`

```
dpkg -i octez-ubt220-unoff-client_16.0rc3-1_amd64.deb \ octez-ubt220-unoff-node_16.0rc3-1_amd64.deb
```

`addgroup tezos`

`adduser --ingroup tezos tezos`

`mkdir -p /var/tezos/node`

`chown -R tezos:tezos /var/tezos`

`sudo su - tezos`

```
octez-node config init --data-dir /var/tezos/node \
            --network mumbainet \
            --history-mode=rolling \
            --net-addr="[::]:9732" \
            --rpc-addr="127.0.0.1:8732"
```

`systemctl enable octez-node.service`

`systemctl start octez-node.service`

Then I wanted to view the progress of the node in the log file but it seems it crashes evry time and restarts?

`tail -f /var/log/tezos/node.log`

Also when I monitor the progress of the sync with the network using bootstrap command nothing happens.

`octez-client bootstrapped`

This is what happens all the time:
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use `--network https://teztnets.xyz/mumbainet` instead of `--network mumbainet`

Comment: This worked and got the confirmation that my node is bootstrapped, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

the article was written just before the Mumbainet reset on Thursday... so you need to use the URL as Nicolas suggests. You will need to dump your node directory, reimport the snapshot and start again I'm afraid.

I will see if we can get the article corrected.

Comment: This worked and got the confirmation that my node is bootstrapped, thank you!